# Where should I put text style in my resources?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

So I have a `styles.xml` with the following:

```
....
<style name="TextAppearance.CustomTheme.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"
                parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">{text_style}</item>
</style>
...
```

Note that text_size is defined in `dimens.xml` file. I **need** to have the textStyle value stored in another file also similar to the textSize, but I don't know where should I put it. There doesn't seem to be a resource type for text style (normal, bold, italic).

The reason that I need to have it in another file is so that this way I can have only one `styles.xml` and then multiple other files (`dimens.xml`, `colors.xml`, etc) that change depending on size screen, etc. So I end up having **only one** styles.xml on /values and then multiple values folders (\values-sw480dp, \values-sw720dp) with different `dimens.xml`, `colors.xml`, etc files.

Furthermore, I tried referencing a string like shown below, but it's not valid.

```
<item name="android:textStyle">@string/text_style</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's not possible to do it. Looking at [TextView's textStyle attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextStyle)  reference it looks that it doesn't accept a reference since the documentation for this attribute doesn't state the following, as other attributes do:

> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

It only states the constants it accepts (and combination of them with |).

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I programmed "bold" in the android:textStyle attribute in my styles.xml resource file.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="questionStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <style name="android:textStyle">bold</style>
    <style name="android:textSize">18sp</style>


</style>
```

If that answer is what you mean. Sorry if I didn't understand your question.